# How to show circular indicator on flutter chewie player on network loss

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I am working on a project where I am using flutter chewie player for playing videos. But when there is no network (or when I turned off the internet), it is showing an error as:

`VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null`

Instead of this error, I want to show a circular indicator on network loss and want to resume playing when network is restored. How to implement this?

My chewie controller is below:

````
    chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        autoPlay: true,
        looping: false,
        startAt: Duration(seconds: timeWatched),
        errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              errorMessage,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          );
        },
        showControls: true,
        allowFullScreen: true,
        fullScreenByDefault: false,
        customControls: CupertinoControls(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          iconColor: COLORS['PRIMARY_COLOR'],
        ));```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus/example) package from pub.dev, and listen to the change in user's device connectivity.

```
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();

  subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
    // Got a new connectivity status!
  })
}
```

You can perform different operations whenever the device connectivity status changes. Like showing `CircularProgressIndicator()` when status changes to ConnectivityResult.none and resume playing (hide indicator) when status changes to `ConnectivityResult.wifi` or `ConnectivityResult.mobile`.

Don't forget to dispose the subscription:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: but will it be resumed when the connectivity is back back in video player.. and the error can be hidden?

Comment: Yes, the subscription above keeps listening to the connectivity of the device, if it changes, it gives you a new result status.